# Problems in sharding in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am currently working on sharding. I have certain issues related to sharding :

1.If I load data again to a collection which is already sharded, the data stays only in one shard and not migrating to the other shard. I don't know the exact reason why this is happening?

2.I loaded data into the primary shard. When I enable sharding to that database, half of the data is present in the primary shard and the remaining data is lost . I could see the warning in the log file as :

warning: moveChunkCmd deleted data already in chunk

I don't know how to proceed with this. It will be helpful if someone help with this

My sh.status() looks like this :

```
shards:
        {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "172.16.2.61:27017" }
        {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "172.16.2.56:27017" }
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
        {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0001" }
        {  "_id" : "Testdatabase",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard000
1" }
                Testdatabase.testcol
                        shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
                        chunks:
                                shard0001       2
                                shard0000       2
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong(
"-4611686018427387902") } on : shard0001 Timestamp(2, 2)
                        { "_id" : NumberLong("-4611686018427387902") } -->> { "_
id" : NumberLong(o) } on : shard0001 Timestamp(2, 3)
                        { "_id" : NumberLong(o) } -->> { "_id" : NumberLong("461
1686018427387902") } on : shard0000 Timestamp(2, 4)
                        { "_id" : NumberLong("4611686018427387902") } -->> { "_i
d" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(2, 5)
        {  "_id" : "inputdata",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0001"
}
```

Thank you,
Priya

Comment: Priya, do you connect to the sharded cluster via a `mongos` (not the s) or directly?

Comment: I connected through mongos. Everything goes fine. The chunks are splitted. But I am not able to see the chunks in the other shard.

Comment: Please post the output of `sh.status()` and `rs.status()` (the latter of both shards), if applicable.

Comment: I have posted sh.status() in the question and I didn't try sharding with replica set yet

Comment: Sorry, to get this done: your number of config servers and their respective hosts plus the host with the mongos instance together with it's `configdb` sting.

Comment: I think your config database and especially  config.chunks has been corrupted. I suggest you to re-create the env with 3 config servers and 2+ mongos. Was any node restarted or crahed during sharding?

Comment: @Antonis: A node restart during a chunk migration should not make any difference, since the chunk migration would simply be redone. If config.chunks would be corrupted, I doubt that sh.status() would not complain.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg This configuration has 1 mongos and 1 config, i dont know what might happen during move commit if config goes down. sh.status() just shows what suppose to show if you just shard using hash. The default is 2 chunks per shard. I have seen that again in the past. I would like to see the the config.chunks collection and the config.changelog.

Comment: @Antonis: If a chunk is moved, the data is transferred and only after an successful transfer the data is applied to the data files and the metadata is updated. As long as the config server is not reporting any problems, the metadata is save to be assumed. But investigating into that topic might still be interesting.

Comment: I have another problem now. If I do sharding after the data is loaded, partition happening but in the secondary shard data is not present. But if I enable sharding and then load the data, the data is not even partitioned. It looks very strange actually

Comment: I have tried sharding with 3 config server, 2 shards and single query router. But the same result is coming. I dont know where the issue is?

Comment: Did you shard everything from scratch? Delete all data directories on mongod and config servers and rebuild the topology? Which version of mongo using?

Comment: Ya, I sharded from the scrath. Deleted all the entries before. I am using MongoDB-2.6.4